# JSP динамические названия переменных

Tags: jsp

У меня задача, сделать сохранение данных на странице при ее обновлении.

Т.е. на JSP у меня есть код, отрисоввывающий checkbox'ы. Их наименования и количество мне неизвестны.

```
<c:forEach items="${trunks}" var="trunk">
 <jsp:useBean id="trunk" scope="page" type="ru.bityard.pojo.Trunk"/>
  <tr>
   <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="${trunk.name}" 
           value="${trunk.name}" 
           <%= ("on".equals(checkbox) ? "checked" : "") %>
    />
    ${trunk.name}
   </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

есть контроллер, который принимает PostMapping , выполняет, что ему нужно и в том числе передает все параметры на GetMapping.

```
@PostMapping
 public String call(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  ...
        // Вытаскиваю все параметры, со всеми значениями
        Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();

        // Записываю все параметры в модель и передаю на GetMapping
        model.addAllAttributes(parameters);

        return "redirect:/missedCalls";
    }

@GetMapping
    public String create(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        ...
        model.addAllAttributes(request.getParameterMap());
        return "missedCalls";
    }
```

И вот тут я не знаю, как сделать проверку, что если у переменной значение "on", то ставим признак "checked". Так как у меня имя переменной задается динамически=${trunk.name}

Я не могу понять , как передать в это выражение вместо заглушки `(checkbox)` имя переменной:

`<%= ("on".equals(checkbox) ? "checked" : "") %>`

Comment: Допустим имя переменной у Вас есть. А где же её значение?

Comment: Map<String, String[]> parameters - ключ имя, валуес[0] значение.

Comment: тогда наверное как-то так `"on".equals(parameters.get(trunk.name)[0])`

Comment: не понял... как появится parameters на JSP?

Comment: А как там появился `trunks`? Примерно так же и `parameters`

Comment: не видит JSP переменную parameters в такой транскрипции...

Comment: Вот такой вариант заработал ${parameters.get(trunk.name)[0] == "on"? "checked" : ""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
<%= ("on".equals(checkbox) ? "checked" : "") %>
```

Вот такой вариант заработал

```
${parameters.get(trunk.name)[0] == "on"? "checked" : ""}
```